# AttributeError: 'ToTensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
age shape: '.format(image.shape))
image = image.reshape([28,28])
print('reshaped image shape: '.format(image.shape))
plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')

print('the label of image'.format(label))

train_loader = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(train, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(test, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

data_train_iter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = data_train_iter.next()

print('shape of minibatch of images:{}'.format(images.shape()))
print('shape of minibatch of labels:{}'.format(labels.shape()))
```

this is my code

and below is the error I am getting

> "C:\Users\CHINTAMANI\anaconda3\envs\conda trial\python.exe" "D:/Python codes/conda trial/main.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:/Python codes/conda trial/main.py", line 15, in 
> print('default image shape: '.format(image.shape))
> AttributeError: 'ToTensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

i am getting this attribute error
please guide me.

Comment: line 3, missing apostrophe '

Comment: `images` has not the right type. You are expecting a tensor but it's a actually a `ToTensor` object https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor